# Verify access token with Database in laravel

Tags: laravel, api, jwt

In my laravel project, I am allowing user to generate a token which will be stored in tenants Database. Now when an API is called ,at that time I want to verify this token with the token stored in DB. How to do that ?? How can I achieve this using middleware ?? Please advise

Comment: Do you have access to the user id? Is the token stored in a separate table from the ```users``` table, what is the structure?

Comment: Please update your question with adequate information.

Answer (score 0):

You could verify it in middleware as follows:

1. create a middleware file with command `php artisan make:middleware EnsureTokenIsValid`
2. Now go to `app/Http/Middleware` and find `EnsureTokenIsValid` middleware. Then, on handle method you should implement your logic with something like:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // you have to get token from database below line is just an example
        $tokenInDatabase = TenanentModel::find(1);

     
        if ($request->input('token') !== $tokenInDatabase) {
            // if token not match redirect to home page
            // or implement your logic
            return redirect('home');
        }
 
        return $next($request);
    }
```

3. Next, you need to register your middleware on `app/Http/Kernel.php` as mentioned in https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes. Example:

```
'ensureTokenIsValid' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnsureTokenIsValid::class,
```

4. Next, add to the route. Example:

```
Route::get('/profile', function () {

   //
})->middleware('ensureTokenIsValid');
```

You could find more details about this on: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#defining-middleware